# Save POST Token in a variavel from function- NODE JS

Tags: node.js, post, axios, token

I'm starting to learn node JS, and I have a doubt to save the return of a token in a variable, to use it in another function, such as doing a GET.

I'm used to Python, where I can return a value, and just declare a new variable with a function, and it will save the return in that variable, but I saw that in NODE JS it doesn't work that way.

It should be simple, but as I'm learning it's still a little confusing and I saw that it has something related to the "Await" scheme.

I even did a simple test, like creating another function with "Await" and then running that function, and it shows the token correctly, but I wanted that token in a variable as I said earlier to use that token in future GETs.

```
var axios = require("axios")



async function getToken(){
    var response = await axios.post('https://url',{ 
        'grant_type':'client_credentials',
        'client_secret': 'client secret',
        'client_id': 'client id'},{
        headers: 
        {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
        }
        
        })
        return response.data.access_token;


       
}

async function test(){
    var token = await getToken();
    
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

async - await keywords pattern with arrow function expression is much cleaner in node.js.
it asynchronous, promise-based behavior so that code could be written a lot cleaner and avoid promise chains (like new Promise/than pattern).

### This Demo code is example for axios.post call with local running `Keycloak` token server.

It assigned a variable `token` and print it.

```
const axios = require("axios")

const getToken = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/example/protocol/openid-connect/token',
        new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
            'client_secret': 'D0caHQ0Z1Z8eR1EjzfOtAXarPiYzBkLQ',
            'client_id': 'test'
        }),
        {
            headers:
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
            }
        })
    return response.data.access_token
}

const test = async () => {
    const token = await getToken()
    console.log("access token: " + token)
}

test()
```

### Result

```
$ node get-token.js
access token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJGSjg2R2NGM2pUYk5MT2NvNE52WmtVQ0lVbWZZQ3FvcXRPUWVNZmJoTmxFIn0.eyJleHAiOjE2Njk1MTAzNDQ
sImlhdCI6MTY2OTUwNjc0NCwianRpIjoiYTliNTM1NWItZGVlNi00OWExLTkzYmEtYmM1Y2YwMzUzYWU0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2V4YW1wbGUi
LCJhdWQiOiJhY2NvdW50Iiwic3ViIjoiNDdjM2M0NjYtNmE2Ny00ZmFiLTk2YTMtNGJiMTdlOWYxZWI1IiwidHlwIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwiYXpwIjoidGVzdCIsImFjciI6IjEiLCJhbGxvd2VkLW9ya
WdpbnMiOlsiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwIl0sInJlYWxtX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyIsImRlZmF1bHQtcm9sZXMtZXhhbXBsZSIsInVtYV9hdXRob3Jpem
F0aW9uIl19LCJyZXNvdXJjZV9hY2Nlc3MiOnsiYWNjb3VudCI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJtYW5hZ2UtYWNjb3VudCIsIm1hbmFnZS1hY2NvdW50LWxpbmtzIiwidmlldy1wcm9maWxlIl19fSwic2NvcGU
iOiJwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIiwiY2xpZW50SG9zdCI6IjE3Mi4xOS4wLjEiLCJjbGllbnRJZCI6InRlc3QiLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsInByZWZlcnJlZF91c2VybmFtZSI6InNlcnZp
Y2UtYWNjb3VudC10ZXN0IiwiY2xpZW50QWRkcmVzcyI6IjE3Mi4xOS4wLjEifQ.eoHuLlSIlCMTk5LvIVpzMJG5qdPgiY5bvYkAceKELvB-46n4H5ib4DptxkC1JoP-2tQmvbik2x0ECgL4mBMLJg
_F_6gltbhT4wguX4vZcO2VS-BtvJbYFti_-Tfqw_w_YfP-6sv3eYuQVBhvObQclv05t4F30JGpKnh7a8hrvO0
```

Also screen capture to call by Postmen for same POST API call.
[image]

### Reference

[Asynchronous Patterns in Node.js](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/asynchronous-patterns-in-node-js/)

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)