# Quickbook/Intuit API - Refresh token (Oauth2)

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, refresh-token, intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to generate an access token from a refresh token on the OAuth2 of Intuit API (in order to access to the Quickbook API).
I achieve to do it in Node.js with the library axios on my laptop, but axios is not available on my server, where my script will be executed.
And i doesn't achieve to do it with another library (https, xmlhttprequest, oauth, node-fetch), it'a a non-sense ! Requests return me error 400 Invalid request, so it doesn't help a lot.

```
Here is the script on axios, which works :
```

```
async function quickbookTokenDirect(){
    let url = 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer'
    let header = {
        Authorization:'Basic <Authorization code found on https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground>',
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    let body={
            grant_type : 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token : '<Refresh token found on https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground>',
    }
    let result = await axios({method:'post', url:url, headers:header, data:body})
    .then( response=>{console.log(response)})
    .catch( response=>{console.log(response)})
}
```

```
There is the script on https, that doesn't works and i doesn't see why :
```

```
async function quickbookTokenHttps(){
    const https = require('https')
    //let url = 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer'
    let header = {
        Authorization:'Basic <Authorization code found on https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground>',
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    let body={
            grant_type : 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token : '<Refresh token found on https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground>',
    }
    let options = {
        hostname:'oauth.platform.intuit.com',
        path:'/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer',
        method:'post',
        headers:header,
        data:body,
        //body:body
    }
    let req = await https.request(options, (res) => {
        let result=''
        console.log(res.statusCode)
        console.log(res.statusMessage)
        res.on('data', (chunk) => result +=chunk)
        res.on('end', () => {console.log(JSON.parse(result))})
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {console.log(err)})
    .end()
}
```

```
If some of you have an idea, it will help me a lot !
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get the refresh token using Intuit node.js example.

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth2-nodejs

The `https.request` header's filed needs a single quotes
And Authorization Basic needs to combine clientID and ClientSecret

From

```
    let header = {
        Authorization:'Basic <Authorization code found on https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground>',
        Accept:'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
```

To

```
    let header = {
        'Authorization':'Basic btoa(toString(<clientID>) + ':' + toString(<clientSecret>))',
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
```

Get well-known URLs

```
https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration
```

Response

```
{
  "issuer": "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2",
  "token_endpoint": "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://sandbox-accounts.platform.intuit.com/v1/openid_connect/userinfo",
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://developer.api.intuit.com/v2/oauth2/tokens/revoke",
  "jwks_uri": "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/op/v1/jwks",
 ... removed
```

Add redirect URL in Intuit.com of [developer portal](https://www.developer.intuit.com/app/developer/homepage) in your project at [dashboard](https://www.developer.intuit.com/app/developer/dashboard).

[image]

```
http://localhost:3000/callback
```

[image]

[config.json](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth2-nodejs/blob/master/config.json) at `oauth2-nodejs` directory

```
  "clientId": "your client id",
  "clientSecret": "your client secret",
  "redirectUri": "http://localhost:3000/callback",
  "configurationEndpoint": "https://developer.api.intuit.com/.well-known/openid_sandbox_configuration/",
  "api_uri": "https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/",
```

At the same directory

```
npm install
node app.js
```

Debugging Refresh code in VS code
[refresh token](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth2-nodejs/blob/master/tools/tools.js#L84)

[image]

refresh token in middleware(client-oauth2)
[image]

Browser login

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

[image]

Just login before refresh token

[image]

After refresh token

[image]

Again the [basic Auth code](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth2-nodejs/blob/master/tools/tools.js#L16) and [this line](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/oauth2-nodejs/blob/master/tools/tools.js#L106)

```
  this.basicAuth = require('btoa')(authConfig.clientId + ':' + authConfig.clientSecret)
```

```
    request({
      url: 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + tools.basicAuth,
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      form: {
        refresh_token: token,
        grant_type: 'refresh_token'
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Bench Vue, 
but i had already tried, and just retry now and i still have a the same 400 error.
And i use the library https and not http, i don't know if it changes something

Comment: @kevin,
Sorry makes you confuse without testing my-self at the first time, Now I tested it and capture screen, hope to address it.

Comment: Wow, So detailed ! Thanks you Bench Vue, i will try it as soon as i can

Comment: I finnaly had time to try it for several days to be sure.
It doesn't work for me, but i can do it more simple : i can found my refresh_token directly on my intuit account https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground, then save it on my database (and update it all 3 months). 
(Futhermore, it is an application for users, so i can't ask them to connect to my intuit account to get themselve the famous refresh_token.)

Comment: So i can concentrate my research on how to use the refresh_token in order to receive a simple new token each hours. I achieve to do it with axios, but my server doesn't accept this library, so i tryed with superagent, request, https, fecth, xmlhttprequest, but no one work, however i put the same data than axios ! I don't get the point, and add singles quotes on my header doesn't change the issue, i still have 'invalid request' with a 400 html error, and it happens only when a speack with intuit.

Comment: @kevin , Can you confirm two items, what version of axios  you using? and did you register your redirect URIs in your account? I will test playground when I return home.

Comment: I'm using axios version 1.1.3, and i didn't add a redirect uri (intuit doesn't accept localhost, and it seems not required to refresh a token)

Comment: axios v1.1.3 is fine to use, redirect uri , I success-ed as I attached image in my answer. try `http://localhost:3000` instead of `https://localhost:3000`

Comment: Also axios post call needs to use `URLSearchParams` instead of data if you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. see this [threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74562135/save-post-token-in-a-variavel-from-function-node-js/74586545#74586545)

Comment: @kevin, the `redirect URI` with localhost  only can add in Development Settings. I think you try set in `Production Settings` correct?

Comment: Yes i try to fix redirect URI in Production settings and not un Development Settings.
I finnaly find a way to do my request with the librarie request, i will take time to make a full response if ever someone else also meet this issue.
Thanks a lot again for your help Bench Vue ! I will try again with axios the next week i guess

Comment: @kevin, Got it thanks your for your update. don't forget to vote me.